# How can we change the text of a textview on clicking of that textview in a custom list view if we are having lots of textview in a row?

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, android-custom-view

Attached is a link to a screenshot of my app and a link showing a video of the functionality i want to achieve.Basically what i want is that when i click the "More" button on any ribbon,it should expand itself and replace the text with data fetched from a JSON file.
The height of the ribbon should adjust according to the amount of text that has to be shown.
Each ribbon has its own custom text which is being fetched from a JSON file.

Currently what is happening is that when i click the "More" button on one ribbon,it shows the text in its own ribbon & other ribbons randomly.Ribbon,means the coloured background.

In detail,Each "More" button is a text view,unique to each ribbon.Every ribbon has its own "More" text view.
Iam currently setting the ID for each text view "More" two times.First they are predefined in a master layout in an XML file and the second time,dynamically when i inflate the master layout in my list view where i assign a unique id for each "More".
But for some reason after setting the ids dynamically,on clicking "More",the code is sometimes fetching the predefined id of the master layout "More" from R.java and sometimes it is fetching the dynamically set id which i set during runtime by the setId() method.

[Link to show the functionality i want on "More" Click](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gujnedff0deewz8/More%20Slider.flv)

[Link to show the screenshot of my app activity(view)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d6bbvsk0cjdd6o2/Screenshot_2014-02-12-14-32-21.png)

Here is my Code of list adapter

```
    public class CustomListAdapter  extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener{
  ListView lv;
 public Activity activity;
   private ArrayList data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
     public Resources res;
    List_Model tempValues=null;
    public Context context;
    ViewHolder holder;
    public String furl;
    ViewGroup vig;
    View vi;


       public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList data, Resources res) {
    super();

    this.activity = activity;
    context=activity.getApplicationContext();
    this.data = data;
    this.res = res;
      inflater = ( LayoutInflater)activity.
              getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(data.size()<=0)

        return 1;

    return data.size();
    }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
    }
       public static class ViewHolder{

       public TextView Text_shopName,Text_distance,Text_date1,Text_date2,Text_website;
     public TextView     Text_phoneNo,Text_Address,Text_Info,TextDirection,Text_more,Text_Like,Text_Bookmark,Text_Remind;
       public LinearLayout LayoutBase ,like_layLayout,layoutmore;;
       public WebView web,shareweb;
        public ListView lv;


        public ImageView image;
        public ImageButton flike_btn;

         public String dest_latitude,dest_longitude;

       }

   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup Parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      vi = convertView;
     vig=Parent;


           holder=new ViewHolder();
          if(vi==null)
         {


        vi=inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_items,null);
        holder.lv=(ListView) vi.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        holder.Text_more=(TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.TextView_More);


          vi.setTag(holder);

         }
        else
      `enter code here` {
         holder=(ViewHolder) vi.getTag();


     }
     if(data.size()<=0)
     {

 Toast.makeText(activity, "No data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
     else
     {
        tempValues=null;
        tempValues=(List_Model) data.get(position);


        **holder.Text_more.setId(position);**

      Log.i("TAg","holder id"+holder.Text_more.getId());
        //holder.Text_more.setTag(position);


        }

     holder.Text_more.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));

     return vi;



}
 private class OnItemClickListener  implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{           
     public int mPosition;
     private View vieww;

     OnItemClickListener(int position){
          mPosition = position;

         // view =vi;
          //Log.v("CustomAdapter","i am in onitem"+mPosition);
     }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Log.v("CustomAdapter","i am in onclick");
           tempValues=(List_Model) data.get(mPosition);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*switch(v.getId())
        {
           case R.id.TextView_more:

                        holder.Text_more.setText(tempValues.getMoreInfo()));

                      break;


        }*/

        if(v.getId()==mPosition)
        {
            TextView morrr=    (TextView) v.findViewById(mPosition);
            morrr.setText(tempValues.getMoreInfo());
            Log.v("textview","pos="+mPosition+tempValues.getMoreInfo());

        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "text not added"+v.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show();
        }

    }




     }
```

Comment: I couldn't understand what exactly what you want, maybe would be better if you show us some code.

Comment: Hi,Thanks to have a look,i have put my code where i am inflating my each row and setting my json data over list view row.

Comment: Can you put your logging back in your onItemClickListener and show the output

Comment: Hi sorry to say but i am not getting your point ,can you please explain it???i have shared two links above, one with what i want to achieve and other one is the screen shot of my app activity..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution of my above query.It works for me..
 Here is the Sample of my code..

Adapter Class:

```
public class CustomListAdapter  extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener
  {
 public Activity activity;
  private ArrayList<JSONObject>data;

public Context context;  
  public String furl;
  LayoutInflater inflater=null;

 public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<JSONObject>data) {
  super();

  this.activity = activity;
  context=activity.getApplicationContext();
  this.data = data;  
   inflater = ( LayoutInflater)activity.
        getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

 @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
     return data.size();
      }
  @Override
 public long getItemId(int position)
  {  
  return position;
  }


@Override
public Object getItem(int position) 
{
    return data.get(position);
}



       public static class ViewHolder
       {

        public TextView txtShort;
          public TextView txtLong;       
         public TextView txtMore;        
      }

   @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup Parent) 
    {   
 View view=convertView;
 if (view==null) {
     convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_row, null);
}

  final TextView txtShort=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_main);
  final TextView txtLong=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_detail);
  final TextView txtMore=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_more);


   if(data.size()<=0)
   {

   Toast.makeText(activity, "No data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  else
 {
   try{
      final JSONObject jsonObject=data.get(position);
      txtShort.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));
       if (jsonObject.getBoolean("isExpand")==true)
       {
           txtLong.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
           txtShort.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
      }else
      {

          txtLong.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
         txtShort.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
      }

       txtMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
       {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            try {

                if (jsonObject.getBoolean("isExpand")==true) 
                {
                    txtLong.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
                    txtShort.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    jsonObject.put("isExpand",false);
                }else
                {                           
                    txtLong.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
                      txtShort.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                      jsonObject.put("isExpand",true);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
   }catch(Exception ex)
   {

   }
  }
```

List_Main_Activity Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView listView=null;
ArrayList<JSONObject> arrayListjsonObj=new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
CustomListAdapter adapter=null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    insertjsonObject();
    adapter=new CustomListAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrayListjsonObj);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;
}



public void insertjsonObject()
{
    arrayListjsonObj.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("name", "name "+i);
        jsonObject.put("address", "address "+i);
        jsonObject.put("isExpand", false);
        arrayListjsonObj.add(jsonObject);
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

its try only.. add setId to more... (textview) ViewHolder's in CustomListAdapter by ur arraylist size eg - size of ArrayList data = 10 in for loop setId to the textview more... as 1001 and for the below group as 2001 --- in ClickListener get id of ur mPosition. if ur postion is 3 -- then ur id must be 3001 by adding 1000 to it. then settextby ur code

Comment: its not working..check my above code,i have done the same same task,i set the id by using holder.Text_more.setId(position),